# BindingGroup in WinRT

Tags: c#, binding, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Does someone know if the [BindingGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.data.bindinggroup.aspx) still exists in the developpement of Windows Store Apps, with WinRT ? It was a very useful tool to cancel or commit an edit. I can't find it in the new documentation.

If you want to know about it, [here](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/01/bindinggroups-for-total-view-validation/) is an example.

I'm working on a list of contacts and I can edit each of them. But if a field isn't valid, I don't want it to be saved. Maybe there is some walkaround approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe to say there's no built-in `BindingGroup` support in WinRT just by checking documentation:

- [`Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.aspx) class has no [`BindingGroupName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.bindinggroupname.aspx) property
- [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Data`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj218365.aspx) namespace contains no [`BindingGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindinggroup.aspx) class.